# Delay with tr:hover using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-tables

I have noticed there's an small delay trying to highlight a row using `tr:hover td` over Chrome browser (tested on version 26).

If you move the cursor fast over the table you will notice the row under it is not already highlighted.

I am using this css:

```
tr:hover td {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here's the fiddel when you can see the small delay:
http://jsfiddle.net/5VJ8n/89/

Is there any way to solve it? 
Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any noticeable delay. Are you running on a slow connection or an old pc?

Comment: No, the PC is quite fast. Connection shouldn't be a problem although its good.

Comment: I've also noticed this issue...do you know what is causing this?  What's interesting is that using jQuery to apply the background with the same selector takes the lag off (this is very counterintuitive)

Comment: @Victor No idea yet Victor... thanks for pointing it out that jQuery seems to be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in webkit ([for quite some time now](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26662)). You can get a little speed boost if you wrap the content in `divs` and then target the div in the hover.

```
<tr>
  <td><div>One</div></td>
  <td><div>Two</div></td>
  <td><div>Three</div></td>
</tr>

tr:hover div {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This achieves exactly the same and works perfectly:

```
td:hover, td:hover ~ td {
//css here
}
```

Comment: The bug seems to have been fixed in Chrome time ago. Now it all works ok.

Comment: I just tried tr:hover and still got the delay. Strange!